# Comparison of measurement methods

Tags: measurement

I have three sets of measurements (A, B, and C) of the same thing. One of them is the gold standard (say A). I want to determine if B and C overestimate or underestimate the true measurement (which is A) and by how much. Can I simply use the sum squared error between A and B, and A and C? If not, which other statistical tool can I use to determine that?

The measurement is a distance in centimeters and there are 32 subjects in the study.

Comment: The "gold standard" is more accurate then other measurement methods but it is not exact.

Comment: But I want to presume it is. It's the best possible measurement, sure, but it is also a costly one.

Comment: Assuming that it is perfect oversimplifies the situation.

Comment: Looks like a job for a regular linear model.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by slightly simplifying the problem to only consider the comparison of A (the "gold standard") versus B (the "experimental" measurement).

There are two questions here. The first is whether measurement B systematically over/underestimates the true measurement. For this, you can use a [Wilcoxon signed-rank test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test). This would be a nonparametric approach, since you are not assuming anything about the distribution of the errors (where $error=A-B$). However, if you assume that the errors are normally distributed (which may or may not be a reasonable assumption; more info from you on what you're measuring and how you're measuring it would be needed to assess the reasonableness of this assumption), you could use a [paired-sample t-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Paired_samples).

This being said, with a sample size of 32, it is unlikely that you will have the statistical power necessary to be able to detect a difference even if one exists (unless the difference is very large). Are you able to obtain more measurements?

For the second question - if there is a significant difference between the tests, how big is this difference? In theory, you could calculate a confidence interval (e.g. via bootstrapping) for the error in your measurement ($A-B$), but again, your sample size is very small and the confidence interval will be very wide (and probably not useful).

If you still want to know the details of how this would be done, let me know and I can add to this answer.

Comment: Actually, there are two groups of individuals. A control and an experiment group with 32 and 34 individuals respectively. Maybe, to check if B systematically under/overestimates A, I can use all 66 individuals as one group. Gathering more data than that isn't viable atm. --- I think it's safe to assume the error is normally distributed (A is measured on a tomographic image and B is measured directly on the subject with a specific tool, like a special ruler).

Comment: Let's say A's avg is 20 +- 0.87 and B's avg is 19.3 +- 0.77 (95% CI). Pearson's correlation is 0.89 (p=2.9e-22). And that paired t-test gives p-value = 0.00086 and t-value = -3.5. Which to me seems to indicate that B underestimates A. (They are correlated and there is a significant difference). I don't know how to get to the "by how much it underestimates" given the t-value, tho (from what I searched, the t-value is measured in stddev units). Am I completely off track here? Also, I'm not sure how to do the bootstrapping you mentioned.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're calculating these CIs and p-values, but if you post your data in a googledoc (and link to it from this post), I'd be happy to demonstrate both the Wilcoxon test and the paired t-test.